# Why last digit in a string is not matched by a regex group?

Tags: java, regex

```
String line = "This order was placed for QT3000! OK?";
String pattern = "(.*)(\\d+)(.*)";

// Create a Pattern object
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

// Now create matcher object.
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
if (m.find( )) {
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(3) );

}else {
    System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

Output:

Found value: This order was placed for QT3000! OK?

Found value: This order was placed for QT300

Found value: 0

Found value: ! OK?

Question: I don't understand why group 2 doesn't have 300 and just 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `.*` is greedy. Meaning that it'll try to match as much as it can.

So the first group first matches **the whole** string, but then `\\d+` fails to match the end of line. So the regex engine backtracks and tries to match one character less. It keeps doing that until

> This order was placed for QT300

is matched, and then `\\d+` matches the "0" that comes next. Finally, the last group matches to the end of the string.

If you want to extract only the number, use `\\d+`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of **greedy** `.*` before `\d+`. `.*` matches as many character as possible before backtracking just one position to allow matching `\d+` which means single digit is captured in 2nd group.

Also you don't need 3 groups to capture number. Just use this regex:

```
\d+
```

to capture a number.

**Code:**

```
String line = "This order was placed for QT3000! OK?";
String pattern = "\\d+";

// Create a Pattern object
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

// Now create matcher object.
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
if (m.find( )) {
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
}else {
    System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

**Output:**

```
Found value: 3000
```